# HttpClient HTTP/2 call to APN from Azure Function

Tags: c#, .net-core, azure-functions, dotnet-httpclient, http2

I am using HttpClient to send Apple Push Notifications to APN HTTP/2 server. I've managed to get it working by using `System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler` nuget package:

```
var http = new HttpClient(new WinHttpHandler());
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri(url))
{
    Version = new Version(2, 0),
    Content = new StringContent(json)
};
// Set headers... Send... Read response... HTTP 200 OK
```

This works good on Windows. The problem is, WinHttpHandler is not supported anywhere else. For example I can't run this code from Azure Functions. My question is - is there any cross-platform way of sending HTTP/2 requests using .NET Core 2.1 or are there any workarounds for Azure Functions 2.0 to get it working?

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue with using WinHttpHandler on Azure Functions 2.0. I have managed to resolve it using the workaround from [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/3052). Basically I put .NET Standard 2.0 System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.dll assembly to the root of the function project and added this:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.dll">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Target Name="CopySPSM" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Copy SourceFiles="System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.dll" DestinationFolder="$(OutputPath)\bin" />
  </Target>
```

With that and a setting WEBSITE_LOAD_USER_PROFILE = 1 to make `CngKey.Import` work to sign the JWT token for APN it started to work.

Answer (score 0):

When your targets .NET Core 2.1 and make an HTTP/2 request, it will downgraded to HTTP/1.1.
You could switch .NET Core 2.1 to a different HTTP stack. And **.Net Core 2.1 currently doesn't support HTTP/2.0**.

So, I suggest that you could switch back to the older stack and that supports HTTP/2.0. For more details, you could refer to this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/32068).